# Make a method which can interact with user interface elements which have .Text property.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text

I am doing a project which has to deal with a lot of text change events. For example :- Changing  Text of `TextBox` , `Label` ..etc 
Is there a way we can create one method that can interact with all user interface elements with text properties ?

The following code I have written is only for `TextBox` user interface elements.
Is there a way i can adjust the code to support all UI elements with Text property ?

```
 public void MailEmptyFieldPopulate(TextBox tbx , string text = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            tbx.Text = "<Empty Field>";
        }
        else
        {
            tbx.Text = text;
        }

    }
```

Comment: All controls have `public virtual string Text { get; set; }`

Comment: @Szer: well, this is not true. This control doesn't have text: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Dennis Ok. All controls which derive from [System.Windows.Forms.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_members(v=vs.90).aspx) have `public virtual string Text { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 public void MailEmptyFieldPopulate(Control ctrl, string text = null)
{
   if(ctrl==null) return;  

   ctrl.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)?"<Empty Field>":text;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean all elements which derives from [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.90).aspx) then you should do this:

```
    public void ChangeText(Control control, string text)
    {
        control.Text = text;
    }
```

If you don't know whether it derives from Control or not, use reflection:

```
    public void ChangeTextReflection<T>(T control, string text)
    {
        var info = control.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
        info.SetValue(control, text);
    }
```